# Conflict with 3 different RewriteRules in .htaccess?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using the below in my .htaccess file.

There 3 types of redirects:

1. redirect to directory /admin/index.php
2. redirect to specific .php files e.g. /about
3. redirect to user profile page from /John

All 3 work on my local environment, but on the server only 1 and 3 works. I'd really appreciate if you can tell me why url redirects of the type '/about' are not working for me.

Many thanks.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options -Multiviews
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^admin$ /admin/index.php [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^about/?$ /about.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^es/?$ /index.php?lang=2 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([_A-Z0-9a-z-+\.]+)/?$ /public_profile.php?id=$1 [L]

</IfModule>

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Comment: Looks good to me, do you have any meaningful errors in the apache logs? You may need to enable rewritelog directive.

Comment: Yup, trying to get that written in httpd.conf by the server admin. I'll keep this thread updated on my outcome. :)

Comment: Have you considered actually redirecting the clients instead of rewriting the filenames internally? Depending on what the user shall see, this might be sensible.